# bison about warnings of shift/reduce

Tags: bison, lex

I wrote a flex/bison prog language parser. Currently is almost done (I belived that was done, only need treat syntax errors). In a specific class, some strange problem occurs.

I belive the problem is in the parser. I stopped read compiling console and, today, I came back to it and saw a bad thing:

```
parser.y: conflicts: 801 shift/reduce, 237 reduce/reduce
```

After that I restart to build the parser and reading the results to catch problems right after made it.

```
input:
    | input expression { std::cout << $2; }
    ;

expression:
      expression comparing expression { $$ = new AExpOperation( $1, $2, $3 ); }
    | expr2 { $$ = $1; }
    | TNEW identifier TLBRACKET TRBRACKET { $$ = new AExpNewArray( NULL, $2 ); }
    | TLPAREN expression TRPAREN { $$ = new AExpParent( $2 ); }
    ;

expr2:
      TPLUS expr2 { $$ = $2; }
    | TMINUS expr2 { $$ = new AExpFastOp( $2, $1, true ); }
    | TBNOT expr2 { $$ = new AExpFastOp( $2, $1, true ); }
    | TNOT expr2 { $$ = new AExpFastOp( $2, $1, true ); }
    | expr2 TINCREMENT { $$ = new AExpFastOp( $1, $2, false ); }
    | TINCREMENT expr2 { $$ = new AExpFastOp( $2, $1, true ); }
    | expr2 TDECREMENT { $$ = new AExpFastOp( $1, $2, false ); }
    | TDECREMENT expr2 { $$ = new AExpFastOp( $2, $1, true ); }
    ;

comparing:
      TEQ | TNE | TLT | TLE | TGT | TGE | TPLUS | TMINUS | TDIVIDE | TMULT | TOR | TAND
    | TBXOR | TLSHIFT | TRSHIFT | TZFILL | TBOR | TBAND | TBNOT | TEQA | TNEA | TINSTANCEOF
    ;

identifier:
      TNUMBER { $$ = new AExpression( $1 ); }
    | TNAME { $$ = new AExpression( $1 ); }
    | TSTRING { $$ = new AExpression( $1 ); }
    | TFALSE { $$ = new AExpression( $1 ); }
    | TTRUE { $$ = new AExpression( $1 ); }
    | TNULL { $$ = new AExpression( $1 ); }
    | TTHIS { $$ = new AExpression( $1 ); }
    ;
```

Just this little part got errors that I didn't understand why:

```
parser.y: warning: 1 useless nonterminal and 9 useless rules
parser.y:40.25-29: warning: useless nonterminal: expr2
parser.y:69.11-28: warning: useless rule: expression: expr2
parser.y:75.11-34: warning: useless rule: expr2: TPLUS expr2
parser.y:76.11-63: warning: useless rule: expr2: TMINUS expr2
parser.y:77.11-62: warning: useless rule: expr2: TBNOT expr2
parser.y:78.11-61: warning: useless rule: expr2: TNOT expr2
parser.y:79.11-68: warning: useless rule: expr2: expr2 TINCREMENT
parser.y:80.11-67: warning: useless rule: expr2: TINCREMENT expr2
parser.y:81.11-68: warning: useless rule: expr2: expr2 TDECREMENT
parser.y:82.11-67: warning: useless rule: expr2: TDECREMENT expr2
```

Why it's saying TPLUS expr2 is useless, for example?

Now I'm wondering How much bad is shift/reduce and reduce/reduce?

Well, I need a clue.

Comment: For the shift/reduce conflicts, do you have any precedence declarations for your operators?  If not, you'd get a huge number of shift/reduce conflicts, since `bison` has no idea what the operator precedence is.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, you do want to resolve your shift/reduce and reduce/reduce conflicts.  A conflict is the parser generator's way of saying that it doesn't know which production you want to be applied, given a particular (ambiguous) input.

I think that "useless" is bison's way of saying that there is no possible input for which the non-terminals `expr2` can be applied.

A couple of observations about your grammar:  (1) Your expression non-terminals seem to be missing rules for `identifier`.  The way I read your grammar, "a + 2" is not a valid expression.  (2) The lack of statement separators bothers me -- it's not wrong, but I think you are introducing chances for ambiguity.  Perhaps that is a constraint of the language you are parsing.

A possible strategy for you: temporarily remove the unary operator features (`expr2`) and get the rest of the parser working; then add that feature back in.

Answer (score 1):

Its telling you that the rule `expr2` can never be reduced, because there is no production for an `expr2` that does not contain a recursive `expr2`, which means that no (finite) input can ever match an `expr2`.

You probably meant to have an `expr2: identifier` production -- adding that will make the `useless rule` warnings go away, but will still leave some shift/reduce and reduce/conflicts to be resolved.